# Fixing Confusion Matrix plot lines

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am trying to plot a confusion matrix as shown below

```
cm  = confusion_matrix(testY.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1))

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=lb.classes_)
disp = disp.plot(include_values=True, cmap='viridis', ax=None, xticks_rotation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image: Confusion Matrix I get]

As you can see, it's showing the axes of the boxes instead of outlining the boxes. I can't see the numbers outside the yellow boxes, because of the axes. I am not good with plots. So I can't find out what I need to change.

What I expect:
[image: Expected Matrix]

**FOUND SOLUTION**

```
plt.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
plt.grid(b=None)
```

Comment: You can use [`plot_confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html)

Comment: try to use sns plot it's simple and written on top of matplotlib

Comment: @Ahx plot_confusion_matrix will be deprecated, so ConfusionMatrixDisplay is preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Turn the grid off

E.g.,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, _ = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.grid(False)

...

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(...)
_ = disp.plot(..., ax=ax, ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cm  = confusion_matrix(testY.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1))

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=lb.classes_)
disp = disp.plot(include_values=True, cmap='viridis', ax=None, xticks_rotation='horizontal')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True` in one of the first cells (for another matplotlib charts). So before the ConfusionMatrixDisplay I turned it off.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True

...

plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(16, 6))

disp_rfc.plot(ax = ax[0], cmap='coolwarm')
disp_cbc.plot(ax = ax[1], cmap='coolwarm')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `cmap` parameter in `plot()` function. It stands for colour-mapping your integer values with colors.

Check

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

for more details.

As the answer

```
cm  = confusion_matrix(testY.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1))

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=lb.classes_)
disp = disp.plot(include_values=True, cmap='Blues', ax=None, xticks_rotation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

Comment: this will solve color problem but not the actual problem he has, You didn't get actual problem.

Comment: He had problem dealing with colors and axes, I gave the solution to color problem, as he already knows how to fix the axes.

Answer (score 0):

The graph which you are showing as example is by sns plot. You can use sns heatmap to plot your matrix.

```
import seaborn as sns
categories = lb.classes_
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True,categories =categories, cmap='Blues')
```